# Mock injected ViewModel

Tags: android, mockito, android-espresso, dagger-2

I need to run Android instrumented test on `StarterActivity`. Here is how it goes

```
public class StarterActivity extends BaseActivity<ActivityStarterBinding> {

    @Inject
    protected StarterViewModel starterViewModel;

    @Override
    public int getContentView() {
        return R.layout.activity_starter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
    }
    //...
}
```

And I call for `starterViewModel` method in onStart.

`StarterViewModel` is injected via a constructor:

```
public class StarterViewModel {

    private final AuthDataModel authDataModel;

    @Inject
    public StarterViewModel(AuthDataModel authDataModel) {
        this.authDataModel = authDataModel;
    }

    @NonNull
    public Single<Boolean> isUserLoggedIn() {
        return authDataModel.isUserLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

I found this really nice approach [Android testing using Dagger 2, Mockito and a custom JUnit rule](https://medium.com/@fabioCollini/android-testing-using-dagger-2-mockito-and-a-custom-junit-rule-c8487ed01b56). But it needs me to add @Provide method. And application component is going to become "God component" with dependencies on a bunch of Modules (or one "God module").

How can I mock in Espresso test without adding @Provide method and overriding it in tests?

Comment: Just a thought (not sure how feasible it really is): have you tried mocking what `getApplicationComponent` returns?

Comment: Yes, this is part of the method I've described in the question. I think I'll go with it, even it needs more @Provides methods.

Comment: No, but I mean mock it just with like a Mockito or something, not necessarily writing the whole Dagger structure.

Comment: You might find my [article][1] useful. It explains how to mock a ViewModel in Espresso tests.


  [1]: https://medium.com/@makovkastar2010/testing-user-interface-of-android-app-with-architecture-components-data-binding-and-dagger-2-5d15c3779807